# i want to use progress bar for uploading data in react native

Tags: react-native, axios, progress-bar

I want to use progress bar for my upload in react native, I am not getting how to use function to create progress bar. I am new to react native.

this is code for upload progress

```
    console.log(progressEvent.loaded, progressEvent.total);
    console.log(
      'Upload progress: ' +
        Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100) +
        '%',
    );
  };
```

this is my upload function using axios

```
axios({
          method: 'POST',
          url: url,
          data: data,
          headers: headers,
          onUploadProgress: uploadProgress,
        })
```

here I want to show my progress bar

```
<View style={styles.buttonStyle}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonTextStyle}>
              Progress={() => uploadProgress()}
            </Text>
          </View>
```

, please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved it, I needed to useState method for it.

```
const [percentage, setPercentage] = useState(0);
```

```
const uploadProgress = (progressEvent) => {
    var Percentage = Math.round(
      (progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100,
    );
    setPercentage(Percentage);
    console.log(progressEvent.loaded, progressEvent.total);
    console.log(
      'Upload progress: ' +
        Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100) +
        '%',
    );
  };
```

```
<Progress.Bar progress={percentage} width={200} />
```

Comment: is your onUploadProgress continuously give the progress update. how could you managed to do that. in my case onUploadProgress called once instantly i.e before the actual upload complete

Comment: you need to pass this function inside your upload onUploadProgress event.